# Пытаюсь сохранить фото из URL с помощью request, фото сохраняется, но формат не поддерживается

Tags: python, requests, urllib

Я хочу сохранить и открыть фото из URL, фото сохраняется, но выдается ошибка при открытии изображения: Похоже, формат этого файла не поддерживается. Думала ошибка в сертификате, похоже, что нет, нашла статью про cookie, но и так не выходит. Видимо img так и остается пустым после get. Прошу помочь.

```
url = 'http://images.amazon.com/images/P/080652121X.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg'
img = requests.get(url, stream=True).content
with open('C:\Progs\Books\out.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло прописать headers в метод get

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
    "Accept-Encoding": "*",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"}
```